# SQL how to sum two rows from the same colum

Tags: sql

[image: table]

The picture shows the table

and my question **calculate and show lily total fees ( teacher + assistant)**

- year 2014 - teacher id (123), assistant id (142)
- year 2015 - teacher id  (523), assistant id (124)

Comment: Please don't use images in your questions, and tag your question with the name of the RDBMS you use.

Comment: Would you like to group by year?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  There is no time component in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a group by?

```
SELECT
    year,
    SUM(charge) charge
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    year
ORDER BY
    year;
```

Comment: The year column is not present in the table, so your SQL statement will not run.

Comment: What column does the OP want to group by the values then?

Comment: I think he knows that in year 2014 there were teacher id = 123 and assistant id = 142, and in 2015 teacher id = 523 and assistant id = 124. This knowledge is not explicitly in the database.

Comment: It would be messy to use a database like that :D

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the table is not really good, for example the year data is missing.

But you can run the following SQL statement which uses union all:

```
select '2014' as year,
       sum(charge)
  from your_table
 where id in (123, 142)

union all

select '2015' as year,
       sum(charge)
  from your_table
 where id in (523, 124);
```